# Convert python to objective-c

Tags: python, objective-c

So I'm trying to convert a some python to it's objective-c equivalent but i'm not having much luck.

The Python code is as follows:

```
def get_next_guess(passwords):
    scores = {}

    for candidate in passwords:

        results = []
        remainder = (x for x in passwords if x != candidate)


    for correct_pw in remainder:
        no_alternatives = len(refine(remainder, candidate, distance(candidate, correct_pw)))
        print(no_alternatives)
        results.append(no_alternatives)

    scores[candidate] = max(results)
    print(scores)
    return min(scores, key = lambda x: scores[x])
```

And my current Objective-C code is:

```
void get_next_guess(NSMutableArray * passwords)
{

NSMutableDictionary * scores = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for (NSString* candidate in passwords)
{

    NSMutableArray * results =  [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray * remainder =  [NSMutableArray new];


    for (NSString * x in passwords)
    {
        if (x != candidate)
        {
            [remainder addObject:x];
        }
    }



    for (NSString * correct_pw in remainder)
    {
        NSUInteger no_alternatives = [refine(remainder, candidate, distance(candidate, correct_pw)) count];
        NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:no_alternatives];
        [results addObject:n];

    }



    NSArray *sorted_Array = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                             @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"intValue"
                                                             ascending:YES]]];

    [scores setObject:[sorted_Array lastObject] forKey:candidate];


}

NSLog(@"table: %@", scores);

}
```

I appreciate that the obj-c code is very rough, I'm just trying to get something that will work. The code is part of a puzzle solver i'm trying to create.

I suspect the (main) problem is around the obj-c version of:

```
remainder = (x for x in passwords if x != candidate)
```

The Obj-c version returns this:

```
table: {
    COELOMS = 4;
    HOLLOES = 4;
    MYOLOGY = 5;
    PADLOCK = 5;
    PARTONS = 4;
    PILINGS = 6;
    POMPONS = 5;
    PRECESS = 6;
    PROSECT = 4;
    SALLOWS = 4;
    TOOLERS = 5;
    TROILUS = 6;
}
```

And the Python version returns this:

```
{'PARTONS': 3,
 'HOLLOES': 3,
 'PADLOCK': 4, 
 'TOOLERS': 4, 
 'COELOMS': 3, 
 'PROSECT': 3, 
 'MYOLOGY': 4, 
 'PRECESS': 0, 
 'TROILUS': 5, 
 'SALLOWS': 3, 
 'PILINGS': 4, 
 'POMPONS': 2}
```

(the Python output being correct)

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your Python code (and your ObjC code, too, though that's less important).

Comment: Changed the python code (it was only slightly out, from when it was copied from Atom).

Comment: What's the specific problem here? What results are you getting, and how do they differ from what you expect?

Comment: I appreciate it's difficult to understand without posting the entirety of both scripts, but I'll edit the question to show the output from each

Comment: Is the Python code you posted here missing something? That first loop only removes the last item in the `passwords` iterable; none of the information from the other iterations is saved, so why are you looping?

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (x != candidate)` to `if (![x isEqualToString: candidate])`.

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't spotted that! Thanks :), there still must be a fault there though as the two versions don't give the same output

Comment: It looks ok, perhaps the error is in the `refine` function?  What does that look like?

Comment: That seems to work when testing, it matches the python version exactly, so somehow this is inducing the error.. can't figure it out though. Can post it if you like though?